# In Safari's "Responsive Design Mode" can you hide all of the device options on top for more screen real estate?

Tags: browser, responsive-design, safari

[image]

Can I hide this?

I'm having a poor user experience debugging my app in Safari (I decided to not use Chrome because it seems to demand more CPU). This bar takes up SOOO much screen real estate and almost forces me to dock the devtools on thee side. But as I said earlier can I hide this?

Comment: It'd be nice if we could also store a combination of settings during the responsive design mode, like screen density, orientation, etc. Unfortunately, seems Safari is the new IE.

Comment: It's strange how Apple with all its eye for design has managed to mess up the responsive view like that.