# Is it possible to adjust the zoom in Safari's "responsive design mode"?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, safari, mobile-website

Is there a way to adjust the zoom in Safari's responsive design mode? The part I highlighted can't be selected unlike the other stuff. I'm using Safari 10.0.1

[image: Safari responsive design mode picture]

I wasn't able to find anyone asking this question let alone answering it. The closest is this: [In Safari's "Responsive Design Mode" can you hide all of the device options on top for more screen real estate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221419/in-safaris-responsive-design-mode-can-you-hide-all-of-the-device-options-on-t)

Seems like a really poor design choice for the browser to automatically adjust the zoom, show the percentage, and then not allow you to alter it...

(I can't believe *this* is my first StackOverflow question.)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing you can't. You have to manually select `x1` from that little dropdown - it's a real pain as that resets on each refresh.

Comment: I seriously can't even see what I'm doing the iPhone is so tiny. Getting flashbacks of working with Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Try and adjust the width and height of the responsive "area" in the responsive view. The adjustment is done using the handles displayed on the left/right middle and the bottom center of the responsive viewport. The aspect ratio of the responsive view area is what determines the zoom level. If you make it very tall, then the zoom level gets reduced to display the entire height of the content in the fixed available space... 
Thanks.